# ms access converting data to field name

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

Good day,
In ms access, I created a form with a combo box that list all products,
a subform(datasheet) that list all companies that sell that product.(the data)

I want the company names(data) to become (in datasheet-subform) the actual field names, in the datasheet, so i can have other details for that company in that column.

Like How You compare phones, with phone name(heading-field name) and it's features under it,

plz
thank you

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean a crosstab query? A subform control will accept a query as a source object.